# if flash name == 'notice' not working in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% flash.each do |key, msg| %>
  <% if key == 'notice' %>
      <%= content_tag :div, "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button> #{key}".html_safe, class: 'alert alert-success alert-dismissable' %>
  <% elsif key == 'alert' %>
      <%= content_tag :div, "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button> #{msg}".html_safe, class: 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissable' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Isn't working for me.

- When I do `<% if true %>` it works.
- When I output the `key`, it says `notice`.

Why isn't it working?

Comment: try using symbols: `if key == :notice` or change the key to a string: `if key.to_s == 'notice'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `Rails 4` and under, flash `key` is a `Symbol` and for `Rails 4.1`, flash `key` is a `String`. I suppose you are using `Rails 4 or under` and comparing against their String equivalents which is root of your problem.

You can resolve it in two ways:

1. Convert the key from Symbol to String and then compare it against String `notice` or `alert`. This way is better because later when you upgrade the Rails version to 4.1 you won't face the current problem again.

   ```
   <% if key.to_s == 'notice' %>
     <%# .. %>
   <% elsif key.to_s == 'alert' %>
     <%# ..%>
   <% end %>
   ```
2. Directly compare with the symbols `:notice` and `:alert`. This will work for now but would not work when you upgrade the Rails version.

   ```
   <% if key == :notice %>
     <%# .. %>
   <% elsif key == :alert %>
     <%# ..%>
   <% end %>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Flash delivers a hash of symbols, the correct way to access them is:

```
if key == :notice

elseif key == :alert
```