# Rails 4 - Flash as Key Value Pair Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, foreach, flash-message

I am trying to use Bootstrap styles to Display the Flash messages with color to the users.

**Controller**

```
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    # Assigning default values
    @category.status = 1.to_i

    if @category.save
      redirect_to admin_categories_path, :flash => { :success => "Category was successfully created." }
    else
      flash[:error] = "Category could not be save. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<%= render 'admin/partials/flash_message' %>
```

Partial

```
<% if flash.present? %>
<%= flash.inspect %>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="<%= flash_class(key) %> fade in widget-inner">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
      <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Helper**

```
  # Flash Messages
  def flash_class(level)
    case level
      when :notice then "alert alert-info"
      when :success then "alert alert-success"
      when :error then "alert alert-error"
      when :alert then "alert alert-error"
    end
  end
```

### Output

I am not able to pass the key to the helper function. I am assuming it sends blank. 
This is the HTML that gets outputted

```
<div class=" fade in widget-inner">
      <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
      Category could not be save. Please try again.
    </div>
```

I am not able to figure out why foreach is not able to extract the key and value pair.
on inspect i get the following

```
#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007fc0e74dfa58 @discard=#<Set: {}>, @flashes={"error"=>"Category could not be save. Please try again."}, @now=nil>
```

Comment: Try this `<div class="<%= flash_class(key).to_s %> fade in widget-inner">`

Comment: possible duplicate of [if flash name == 'notice' not working in rails view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312407/if-flash-name-notice-not-working-in-rails-view)

Answer (score 0):

in Rails 4, it supports only strings. So i had to change the Helper to the following

```
  # Flash Messages
  def flash_class(level)
    case level
      when 'notice' then "alert alert-info"
      when 'success' then "alert alert-success"
      when 'error' then "alert alert-danger"
      when 'alert' then "alert alert-warning"
    end
  end
```

**Edit: According to Deep Suggestions **

By Changing the Flash Partial to

```
<% if flash.present? %>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %> fade in widget-inner">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
      <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And by Just Extendting the BootStrap Classes as follows we can eliminate the Helper class all together.

```
alert-notice { @extend .alert-info; }
alert-error { @extend .alert-danger; }
```

Comment: Why write this helper method at all ? When you can just pass the key to class name like <div class=" alert alert-<%= key %>" > and then extend the class with built in bootstrap class like .alert-notice { @extend .alert-info; }

Comment: damn. why didnt i think of that :D

Comment: i will optimize it once i complete my app. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: It's Rails 4.1 changes, not Rails 4. Another [useful helper for this](https://gist.github.com/roberto/3344628#comment-1215300)